# Convert a single point (lat, long) to raster-projection from a tiff file, and finding the nearest pixel

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, ogr, latitude-longitude

I have a TIFF file and a list of coordinates, of which I'd like to get the information from the TIFF file for each coordinate. I'm quite new to working with geodata, but after a bit of searching I came up with the following strategy:

1. Convert the lat/lon coordinate to the raster-projection of the TIFF file.

```
def create_conversion(tiff_file):
    ds = gdal.Open(tiff_file)
    width = ds.RasterXSize
    height = ds.RasterYSize
    gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    gp = ds.GetProjection()
    data = np.array(ds.ReadAsArray())    

    point_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    point_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    point_srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER) 
    file_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    file_srs.ImportFromWkt(gp)
    
    ct_point = osr.CoordinateTransformation(point_srs, file_srs)  # (source, target)
    gt_inv = gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt)    

    return data, width, height, ct_point, gt_inv
```

2. Find the raster boundaries, and subset my coordinates to only those inside the boundaries.

```
def get_raster_boundries(tiff_file):
    src = gdal.Open(tiff_file)
    ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
    lrx = ulx + (src.RasterXSize * xres)
    lry = uly + (src.RasterYSize * yres)
    
    # Setup the source projection - you can also import from epsg, proj4...
    source = osr.SpatialReference()
    source.ImportFromWkt(src.GetProjection())

    # The target projection
    target = osr.SpatialReference()
    target.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

    # Create the transform - this can be used repeatedly
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

    # Transform the point. You can also create an ogr geometry and use the more generic `point.Transform()`
    ul_lat, ul_lon, _ = transform.TransformPoint(ulx, uly)
    lr_lat, lr_lon, _ = transform.TransformPoint(lrx, lry)
    
    return ul_lat, ul_lon, lr_lat, lr_lon
```

Applying this my TIFF file and coordinates gives me the following boundaries

```
ul_lat: 53.47269154721768, ul_lon: 3.2570915993474303, lr_lat: 53.40881044052881, lr_lon: 7.23727703418233
```

I then take a coordinate that falls within these boundaries.

```
POINT (6.856734653824825 53.41389719308172)
```

3. The last step is to convert that single point to the pixel coordinates corresponding to the raster-projection.

```
def point_conversion(data, width, height, ct, gt_inv, point):
    # Convert point cooridnates to raster-projection
    mapx, mapy, z = ct.TransformPoint(point.x, point.y)
    pixel_x, pixel_y = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_inv, mapx, mapy)

    # round to pixel
    pixel_x = round(pixel_x)
    pixel_y = round(pixel_y)
    
    # Handle points out of map
    if pixel_x >= width or pixel_x < 0:
        # print(f'width: {width}, pixel_x: {pixel_x}, point_x: {point.x}')
        return -505050
    elif pixel_y >= height or pixel_y < 0:
        # print(f'height: {height}, pixel_y: {pixel_y}, point_y: {point.y}')
        return -505050

    return data[pixel_y, pixel_x]
```

Now this should give me the nearest pixel given the coordinate. But For this particular coordinate I get the pixel values of 118785 and 3795 which are outside of the width (131359 ) and height (3786) resulting from the data. While given the boundaries and the coordinate I would expect this to fall in between the width and height. Might be I'm doing something wrong in the conversion steps, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone have an idea how to get it right?

Comment: You can find out how it is done with C++ with https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html from the source code https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp

Comment: 118785 is not outside 131359

Comment: Thanks @user30184! gdallocationinfo with the -wgs84 setting gives me the right pixel values. I guess the -wgs84 setting is something that I didn't apply properly in my code above. The only problem is that I have a rather big set of coordinates to check, and gdallocationinfo is not very fast. Do you have any thoughts on how to speed this up?

Comment: @Vince yeah but 3795 is outside 3786, which indicates the coordinate not being in the raster, while it should be..

Comment: It pays to start the process and gdallocationinfo is made for just single point queries. Try if Sample raster values in QGIS https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/sampling_raster_data.html is faster and study the source code if it is.